# Set proxy for extenions in Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy

I'm trying to use the Grammerly extension on VS code on company issued Mac. The extension seem to have an issue trying to initialize, it give the following error in the OUTOPUT:

```
Initializing...
[Error - 10:09:08 AM] Server initialization failed.
  Message: Request initialize failed with message: fetch failed
  Code: -32603 
[Error - 10:09:08 AM] Starting client failed
  Message: Request initialize failed with message: fetch failed
  Code: -32603
```

I might be wring put my guess is that is due to the proxy settings I'm forced to use by company rules.

I tried adding

```
"http.proxy": "http://user:pass@my.proxy.address:8080",
```

in the settings.json file, but this didn't help.

I also tried changing the proxy support from override to on and this also didn't help.

I'm not entirely sure this's due to proxies, might this error be due to something else?

Comment: As an extension like that can directly lead to information leak, you should first reach out to the company to confirm you are allowed to install it. Don't make mistakes that terminates your job.